# Firebase geofencing with custom shapes

Tags: firebase, geofencing, geofirestore

I am looking to geofence a specific area using Firebase to do things like send alerts to users within a specific area, or perhaps even when they enter an area. I see geosearching capabilities native to Firebase like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries), but I'm not sure that it gives me a true "geofence" solution. Furthermore, it seems like it only allows me to define areas in the shape of a rectangle, I need to geofence using custom polygons.

Any advice on how to best utilize Firebase or other systems for this?

Comment: The docs seems pretty clear *In the Geohash system the world is divided into a rectangular grid*. That being said, with some additional code, you could use those to create somewhat of a custom shape with each having a separate query (this is due to Firestore having a single range clause per compound query). I am not sure what kind of answer you're looking for but there is a lot of information on the internet about building polygonal geofences and you will have to adapt those methods to Firebase.

Comment: I think you're right. The best we can try and do is make shapes with rectangles. Thanks for the input, Jay.